# Visual Studio Critical error[KB2770057] is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Anyone can help? The problem is that exists because something is missing on my computer. 
Last time, I had to reinstall my whole software and  discard Update 4, but maybe there is another option?

[image]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3fc126a0-74ab-4b6f-a924-a1222620f489/error-when-installing-vs-2012-update-3-the-pipe-is-being-closed?forum=vssetup

Comment: What is the exact translation of the error message? I see [there is a mention of kb2770057](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3fc126a0-74ab-4b6f-a924-a1222620f489/error-when-installing-vs-2012-update-3-the-pipe-is-being-closed?forum=vssetup) that suggests it's a web installer issue and you should try the full stand-alone installer (the huge ISO image).

Comment: The screenshot doesn't look like the install for vs2010, it's either vs2012 or vs2013. Which one is it?

Comment: @Willem van Rumpt It is vs2012.